# how to parse a specific sentence?

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

Consider this minimal dataframe

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'text' : [u'the cat eats the dog. the dog eats the cat']})
```

I know I can use `apply` to run spacy on my text column:

```
mydata['parsed'] = mydata.text.apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

However, I would like to do something more subtle:
How can I extract the *sentence* where the *subject* is `dog` using Part-Of-Speech tagging and `spacy`?

Output should be the `extracted` column below:

```
Out[16]: 
              extracted                                        text
0  the dog eats the cat  the cat eats the dog. the dog eats the cat
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a `pandas` question. You have three issues:

1. Split each string to multiple sentences
2. Determine subject in each sentence
3. Return sentence if subject is `dog`

---

**1.** We can split a string into a `list` using `split()` method.

```
my_string = "the dog ate the bread. the cat ate the bread"
sentences = my_string.split('.')
```

**2.** According to the Spacy documentation calling `nlp()` on a `string` will give us a `Doc` which contains `tokens` that in turn have some `properties` attached to them.

The `property` we are interested in is `dep_` since it will tell us the relationship between our `token` and the other `tokens`, i.e. if our `token` is the subject or not.

You can find a list of properties here: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

```
doc = nlp(my_string)

for token in doc:
    print(token.dep_)  # if this prints `nsubj` the token is a noun subject!
```

**3.** In order to check if `token` is equal to `'dog'` we need to grab the text property from the token:

```
token.text
```

---

If we scale this up:

```
NLP = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def extract_sentence_based_on_subject(string, subject):

    sentences = string.split('.')

    for sentence in sentences:
        doc = NLP(sentence)
        for token in doc:
            if token.dep_ == 'nsubj':
                if token.text == subject:
                    return sentence


mydata['text'].apply(extract_sentence_based_on_subject, subject='dog')
```

Comment: spaCy will split the document into sentences, so you don't need to do that manually. You can do `doc = nlp(string)` and then iterate over `doc.sents`.